# How to specify a numeric component parameter for article selection

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

In setting up the parameters for my component,I want one of them to be an article ID that is opened and used. According to [Joomla Standard Parameter Types](http://docs.joomla.org/Standard_parameter_types), text is the only option.

Can integers be specified, or is there a way to validate the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, text is your only *standard* solution.  Joomla does, however, allow for custom parameter types.  You could conceivably do one for integers, but if it's only for article selection, you can do what Joomla does for the com_content component.

1. Create a new folder in *your* admin component called: `administrator\components\com_mycomponent\elements`
2. Copy `administrator\components\com_content\elements\article.php` to your new folder (and index.html for security)
3. You can now specify a parameter type of "article" in your component as shown below, and you'll have a dropdown of your articles in the component configuration.
4. Be sure to include addpath to your elements folder in your "params".

`<params addpath="/administrator/components/com_mycomponent/elements" />`

`<param type="article" name="article_id" default="0" label="Select Article" />`